# Need info on java.io.UnixFileSystem.rename0

Tags: java, unix

Could you please explain the below stack trace, I tried to understand the source code but couldn't enough information on what `rename0()` is doing.

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" RUNNABLE native
java.io.UnixFileSystem.rename0(Native Method)
java.io.UnixFileSystem.rename(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
java.io.File.renameTo(File.java:1248)
com.bea.wli.sb.transports.file.resource.FileResource.renameToUniqueFilePath(FileResource.java:766)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you (or something running on your machine) tried to rename a file or directory.  The major hint comes in the line

```
java.io.File.renameTo(File.java:1248)
```

Without knowing what file was being renamed, or what the new name would have been, it is hard to determine exactly why this won't work.

Comment: The logic is to process a file and writes to a folder. It checks if the files exists in the folder before writing. I am 100% sure the files currently being processed does not exists in that folder, but still it call this function and since there are > 1000 files its processing the thread is getting stuck. This is on unixfilesystem, My question is 1. Is it because the NFS on the unix box is unresponsive or 2. because there are > 1000 files its trying to find the file exists and getting stuck. Also the folder already contains > 10,000 files

Comment: Across NFS?  That introduces a network between your CPU and your disk, and is the root cause of so many non-POSIX like behaviors that even SVN can't use NFS storage for source code control repositories.  Perhaps you should be debugging this at the NFS / operating system layer as Java doesn't get to "know" it's an NFS mount (the operating system hides that information from the JVM).

Comment: I was just thinking can the overload on nfs by these thread trying to search a file whether it exists can cause NFS to go unresponsive?

Comment: Yes.  Especially if such behavior is subject to the whims of a network (dropped packets, sub-optimal routing, server congestion, etc).  Perhaps your 1000 threads are all properly waiting (and then timing out) on a reply from the server who's just been hit by 1000 requests.